# Convertir Blob a XLSX con Vue y Django

Tags: javascript, django, excel, vue.js, openpyxl

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde se requeriran variedad de reportes. Estoy trabajando con Django, Vue.js y la libreria openpyxl. Ya generado una vista como ejemplo:

```py
class DescargarReporte(APIView):    
    def post(self, request):
    
    # each item is a line in the excel sheet
    # it can be anything you pull from the db
        excel_data = [
        ['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4', 'header5'],
        [1,4,5,6,7],
        [5,6,2,4,8]
        ]

        if excel_data:
            wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
            ws = wb.create_sheet()
            for line in excel_data:
                ws.append(line)

        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=archivo.xlsx'

        wb.save(response)

        return response
```

Y en el componente del frontend tengo la funcion:

```
async function descargarReporte(){    
    const res =  await api.post('/ventas/excel/',{
        responseType: 'blob',     
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
            new Blob([res.data], {
                type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"})
        );
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", "archivo.xls");
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href)
    }).    
    catch((error) => console.log(error))        
    return res;
}
```

Al interactuar con el botón que llama la función, se puede apreciar por consola el blob obtenido desde el response:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al descargar el archivo este contiene el blob y no la estructura y datos enviados desde la vista. Adicional a esto, si cambio el formato del archivo de salida a "XLSX" el archivo se descarga como corrupto y sin contenido alguno.

Espero puedan ayudarme ya que tengo dos días con este inconveniente y necesito solventarlo.

Comment: Podrias tambien, para probar donde esta lel problema, guardar el archivo generado en el back, a ver si no es por ahi el tema, de que directamente se este generando mal...

Comment: @gbianchi acabo de verificar y salvando desde el back crea el archivo tal como deseo, con la estructura indicada en la vista. No se si estoy manejando mal el response enviado o no estoy formateando el Blob a un formato manejable.

Comment: Puedes probar `const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(res.data);` porque si entiendo bien `res.data` ya es un blob